# Java - Is it possible to write public void() in Constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, void

I couldn't find information if it is possible to write public void in constructor section. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean "in constructor"? Do you want to declare a constructor as public void ?

Comment: This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.

Comment: you mean declaring a method inside constructor ??

Comment: blacklune, please explain what you want to archive and what you want to use that code for (and maybe add some phantasy-code you're expecting to work). Until now your question is too broad and your intent is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the byte code level, a constructor is always void so it would be redundant to specify it. i.e. the constructor is always called `<init>V` i.e. the `V` is the return type where `V` == `void`. Similarly the static initialiser is `<clinit>V` You will see this notation if you take a stack trace (e.g. print an exception) while in these methods.

The constructor actually takes the object to be initialised as an argument as the object is created before calling the constructor. Note: you can create the object without calling a constructor with `Unsafe.allocateInstance(Class)`

> I couldn't find information if it is possible to write public void in constructor section. Is it possible?

It is not possible to write it as Java distinguishes a constructor from a method is that it must have the same name as the class, and it must not specify a return type.  If you specify a return type, it assumes it's a method.

The notation `x = new Clazz()` also limits the number of return values to 1 which is the object.  There is no easy way to modify this notation to return more than one object. i.e. supporting a return type for constructors would not be easy.

If you want to define a return type, most likely you are thinking of a factor method like this.

```
public static MyInterface createObject() {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

Note how the return type is different to the class actually created, but there is still only one reference returned.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor syntax is defined in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8). Anything else is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

*The question is unclear. Peter Lawrey answered one interpretation, this is an answer to another.*

You cannot declare methods within a constructor. You can, however, declare a class and declare variables.

Because you are able to declare a class within a constructor, you could declare a method inside of a class and then use the class. If the method isn't static you can construct an object of the class.

Answer (score 0):

No, Java only allows a method to be declared within a class, not within another method or constructor.Indirectly you can do something like this :

```
public A() {
  class B {
     public void m() {
     }
         }
    }
```